# Select where id not in (...) has any limit? - NOT IN VS NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select some rows from a catalog which are not related to two table (Table1 and Table2).

The rows in the catalog are related to the tables using the field `idA`.

I am using the following query:

```
;with CTE(id) AS(
select distinct idA from Table1
union
select distinct idA from Table2
)  
select * from Catalog where IdA NOT IN (select id from CTE)
```

The very strange part is that this query does not return any result.

If I use the following query after de CTE it will return some rows

```
select Id from Catalog where not exists (select 1 from CTE where Catalog.IdA = CTE.Id);
```

Does anyone know what is the reason of this? AFAK both queries are equivalents.

Of course the first query is slower than the second one but that is not very important. The important part is, why those queries do not return the same results?

Maybe it's important to mention that Table1 has more than 3.9 million rows
but just 139,283 different values for `idA`. 
Table2 has only some thousands rows

Any help or comment will be appreciated

Comment: If one or more NULL values are returned by the `NOT IN` subquery, the entire result is NULL (unknown). Unknown is not true so the condition is not satisfied and no rows returned.

Comment: To tag onto what @DanGuzman said, that's why you want to be explicit with what column you are returning in the sub-query... or use `exists()`

Comment: @DanGuzman you are absolutely right !! If I add: `WHERE IdA is not null` to the queries in the CTE the problem is solved. If you add an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one or more `NULL` values are returned by a `NOT IN` subquery, the result of the predicate is unknown rather than true or false and no rows returned due to the unsatisfied condition. It is best to avoid `NOT IN` with nullable expressions to avoid this non-intuitive behavior.

Although slighly more verbose, a correlated `NOT EXISTS` subquery will always return true or false and avoid the `NULL` gotcha.